# How do I pass data when the x button is clicked?

Tags: reactjs

So I have a filter chip, and this filter chip is just passed a text body, and close function like so:

```
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import "./FilterChip.css";

function FilterChip({textBody, onCloseClick}) {

    return <div className="filter-chip">
        Category: {textBody} <CloseIcon onClick={onCloseClick} className="filter-chip-close-button"/>
    </div>
}

export default FilterChip;
```

I can render multiple filter chips in one page. How can I tell my parent component that the particular chip's x button has been clicked? Is it possible to pass this data on the `onCloseClick` function? I need to remove the chip once it's x button has been clicked, and I also need to uncheck it from my list of check boxes in my parent component. This is how I render the chips.

```
function renderFilterChips() {
        const checkedBoxes = getCheckedBoxes();

        return checkedBoxes.map((checkedBox) => 
            <FilterChip key={checkedBox} textBody={checkedBox} onCloseClick={onChipCloseClick} />
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass an "identifier" for each chip and then use that identifier to find out "what" was clicked by the user. And then you can filter out the clicked  chip.

```
function FilterChip({ textBody, onCloseClick, id }) {
  const handleOnClose = (event) => {
    onCloseClick(event, id);
  };
  return (
    <div className="filter-chip">
      Category: {textBody}{" "}
      <CloseIcon onClick={handleOnClose} className="filter-chip-close-button" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now your `onCloseClick` should accept a new param `id` and handle the logic to remove the chip .

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need `checkedBoxes` to be in state.

```
import { useState } from "react"

const initialBoxes = getCheckedBoxes()

function renderFilteredChips() {
   const [ checkedBoxes, setCheckedBoxes ] = useState(initialBoxes)
}
```

Then implement a function to remove a checked box by its index (or if you have a unique key identifier that would be even better)

```
const onChipCloseClick = (indexToRemove) => {
   setCheckedBoxes(state => state.filter((_, chipIndex) => chipIndex !== indexToRemove))
}
```

Then when you map over the chips, make sure the function that closes the chip has its index, effectively allowing each chip in state to filter itself out of state, which will re-render your chips for you.

```
import { useState } from "react"

const initialBoxes = getCheckedBoxes()

function renderFilteredChips() {
   const [ checkedBoxes, setCheckedBoxes ] = useState(initialBoxes)

const onChipCloseClick = (indexToRemove) => {
   setCheckedBoxes(state => state.filter((_, chipIndex) => chipIndex !== indexToRemove))
 }

return <>
   {checkedBoxes.map((checkedBox, index) => (
     <FilterChip 
        key={index} 
        textBody={checkedBox} 
        onCloseClick={() => onChipCloseClose(index)} 
     />
    })
  </>
}
```

Obligatory note that I haven't checked this and wrote it in Markdown, so look out for syntax errors (: